# get AuthenticationManager in spring security

Tags: spring, spring-security

how can i get AuthenticationManager bean in my custom class? Classes WebApplicationContext and ApplicationContext do not have method getBean("refBean"). Help me please!

Answer (score 0):

Define an alias for your authentication manager in spring security config:

```
<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
```

Then you can inject it in some spring managed bean using annotations:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("authenticationManager")
private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
```

Note: you need a qualifier because at runtime there are multiple beans of AuthenticationManager type.